# Авторизация в CakePhp

Tags: php, авторизация

Всем привет! Подскажите, в чем проблема. После успешной авторизации попадаю в админ панель, после этого закрываю страничку и открываю заново. В итоге в админ панель пускает без авторизации. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить. Не могу найти настройки, где видать куки (по умолчанию записываются после авторизации).

Answer (score 1):

Привет, во первых при закрытии странички куки остаются(ну до expiry date), а так можно для админки хранить данные в сессию, а после logout удалить их, и с куками тоже самое. а видать куки в настройках браузера, смотря коким пользуешся.

Answer (score 0):

У вашей сессии есть **timeout**. Это всё хранится в Куках.

Если вы перед закрытием страницы не сделали **logout**, то до истечения **timeout** вы можете попасть на страницу даже после закрытия Браузера